# UI5: how to include a png image the icon properties of sap.m.MessagePage

Tags: sapui5

I am still new to UI5 then I have a question, is it possible to put in image such as images/myimage.png instead of sap-icon:// in the property icon of the class sap.m.MessagePage in an xml view ?
I have this tree :

```
webapp  
  /view  
    /myview.view.xml  
  /images  
    /myimage.png
```

i have :

```
<MessagePage 
        title="{i18n>mytitle}" 
        text="{i18n>mytext}"
        description="{i18n>mydesciption}"
        icon='images/myimage.png' 
        showNavButton="true"/>
```

and i don't have my image, in Network i have myimage.png in 404 :( (I am using WebIde)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to give the complete URL of the image. So you may have to use a formatter for icon property of the MessagePage and return a full URL.

Comment: Actually I upload the image to the file "images", with VS code i see the image with webide i don't see the image